# Алгоритм по поиску внешних сторон

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия

Есть программа написанная на js на которой пользователи рисуют план здания, рисуют в 2D и потом преобразовуют в 3D, и нужно найти внешние стороны, чтобы с внешней стороны рисовать кирпичный фасад, а с другой обои. Как найти внешние стороны?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здание всегда цельное, или с дырками внутри, или может быть даже с несвязанными частями?

Comment: Внешние стороны здания (в простом случае) - это результат объединения всех нарисованных 2D объектов. Т.е. это внешний контур плана. Как его найти - объединить все 2D части в одну.

Идете в цикле по всем частям и объединяете их со всеми (алгоритм соединения 2 частей сможете найти?). Если часть ни с чем не объединяется - значит она отдельно-стоящая.

Сложности возникают, если у вас можно нарисовать план с дырками внутри (по типу бублика) или план из нескольких несвязанных частей.

Comment: Спасибо все получилось